# Discrepancy between OS memory and erlang virtual memory?

Tags: ubuntu, memory, erlang, virtual-memory, erlang-otp

My Erlang virtual machine shows 3GB memory usage but OS occupies full RAM and the application getting restarted from time to time. We tried checking remote debugging no process is utilizing more memory in the erlang application. We are using ubuntu 20.04 and OTP 21.

Erlang Application
[image]

OS stats

[image]

[image]

Attaching erlang: memory snapshot.

```
[{total,3498618992}, 
{processes,350739696},
 {processes_used,247996400},
 {system,10047879296},
 {atom,2001161},
 {atom_used,1976059},
 {binary,268084360},
 {code,39873100},
 {ets,2000234488}]
```

Is there anything we should be checking? is it an application issue or an OS issue? How can we fix it?

Comment: As suggested by the reviewer, You should send this to erlang-questions@erlang.org